# Override files from a second source in Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a directory structure like so;

```
foo/
  - main.css
  - widgets.css
  - theme.css
bar/
  - theme.css
  - tinymce.css
```

What I want to achieve in Gulp is create a stream that contains all the files in `foo/` (as in `"foo/**/*.css"`), and then merges them with the contents of `bar/` so that any files that don't exist in the other are added, and the files that exist in the other are overwritten.

In the end, I should have a stream that contains;

```
foo/main.css
foo/widgets.css
bar/theme.css
bar/tinymce.css
```

`bar/tinymce.css` has been added, and `bar/theme.css` replaced `foo/theme.css`. This should also work for all subfolders within `foo` or `bar`.

How do I achieve this? I looked at a few merge packages for Gulp but they seem to just add the files, and never replace them.

Comment: create third directory `xyz`, first move `foo` to `xyz` and then `bar` to `xyz`

Comment: Surely there'd be a way to do it in Gulp directly without having to get fs involved?

Comment: I also need a way to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. The following gulpfile will combine everything from directories `a` and `b` into `final` such that:

1. If a file exists in `b` this this file appears in `final`.
2. If a file exists in `a` but **not** in `b`, then this file appears in `final`.

In effect, the files in `b` "override" those in `a`, and `b` can contain files that are additional to those in `a`.

The core of the solution is to use the `map` method from [`event-stream`](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream) to process each vinyl file as it passes through the stream and then decide what to do with it. Note that the following code treats all problems with creating a vinyl file as "does not exist". You may want to check errors in detail if you want to distinguish permission errors from files that are truly missing.

```
import gulp from "gulp";
import es from "event-stream";
import debug from "gulp-debug";
import vinylFile from "vinyl-file";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

gulp.task("default", (callback) => {
    const a_path = "a/";
    const b_path = "b/";

    // We add the forward slash so that the comparison later works.
    const b_absolute = path.resolve(b_path) + "/";

    return gulp.src([path.join(a_path, "**"),
                     path.join(b_path, "**")], { nodir: true })
        .pipe(debug({title: "before"}))
        .pipe(es.map((file, callback) => {
            // We want all the files in b.
            if (file.base === b_absolute) {
                callback(null, file);
                return;
            }

            // For files in a, we want only those that do not also
            // exist in b.
            vinylFile.read(
                path.join(b_path, file.relative), {base: b_path},
                (err, override) => {
                    // It does not exist in b, so we want it. All
                    // errors are interpreted as "does not exist".
                    if (err) {
                        callback(null, file);
                        return;
                    }

                    // It exists in b, so we don't want it.
                    callback();
                });
        }))
        .pipe(debug({title: "after"}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("final"));
});
```

(In case it needs be said: the code above conforms to ES6. If you name your file `gulpfile.babel.js` and install `babel` or `babel-core`, you'll be able to run the file.)

If I have the following setup:

```
$ find a -type f | xargs -n1 -t cat
cat a/three 
from a
cat a/two 
from a
cat a/one 
from a
cat a/four 
from a

$ find b -type f | xargs -n1 -t cat
cat b/two 
from b
cat b/five 
from b
cat b/four 
from b
```

And I run the gulpfile above, I get:

```
$ gulp
[11:36:10] Failed to load external module babel-core/register
[11:36:10] Requiring external module babel/register
[11:36:10] Using gulpfile /tmp/t12/test2.babel.js
[11:36:10] Starting 'default'...
[11:36:10] before a/four
[11:36:10] before a/one
[11:36:10] after a/one
[11:36:10] before a/three
[11:36:10] after a/three
[11:36:10] before a/two
[11:36:10] before b/five
[11:36:10] after b/five
[11:36:10] before b/four
[11:36:10] after b/four
[11:36:10] before b/two
[11:36:10] after b/two
[11:36:10] before 7 items
[11:36:10] after 5 items
[11:36:10] Finished 'default' after 37 ms
```

And if I inspect `final`:

```
$ find final -type f | xargs -n1 -t cat
cat final/three 
from a
cat final/two 
from b
cat final/one 
from a
cat final/five 
from b
cat final/four 
from b
```